# Joomla: Migrating Undefined when jUpgrade component is used to upgrade from 1.5.26 to 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

[image]

Every steps is successfully finished except for the migration step. Where it starts giving Internal Server errors list. Attached image clearly shows the error and also in console mode the following error can be seen:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) mywebsite.com/administrator/components/com_jupgrade/includes/controller.php?noCache=1392662967309&directory=jupgrade
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) 
GET mywebsite.com/administrator/components/com_jupgrade/includes/controller.php?noCache=1392662988314&directory=jupgrade 500 (Internal Server Error) mootools.js:1**
```

There are many such errors in the console.

Comment: You need to look at the server error log to determine what the underlying error is.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using a migration tool not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

check if you still have the "legacy mode on". I had similar problems with this option set to on. After disabling it everything worked...